# Is it possible to install a hdd then format it?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, desktop-computer, format

I have taken apart a sky box and now have a 500gb HDD (or maybe ide? idk) and SATA cable, I am wondering if I could add it to my PC, boot up my PC then format it so it can be used as a backup or maybe just for games as I am planning to get an SSD in the next few months.

Comment: I don't see any reason why you couldn't do that.

Comment: Nice, I will have a go at that, hopefully nothing goes wrong, will the bios want to talk to me when i load it back up?

Comment: You already have an OS installed on another hard drive in the PC right? Just plug the hard drive into the PC, use a utility to format the drive, and you should be fine.  The BIOS shouldn't be involved.

Comment: Yeah, I have put it in now turns out I did indeed have a few problems, it didn't know where to boot from and kept failing, after messing around in the bios I have just unplugged the floppy drive as I will never use it. Thanks for your help!